# How to get the week count from start date and end date using moment JS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to get the week count from the start date and end date using moment JS. Then I want to push it into an array. If a week is more than one week, I want to show like this `const result = [1, 2, 3];`

```
const dateStart = moment(1517812701107).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
const dateEnd = moment(1518331101107).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

From this start date and end date I need to get the number for week array. Is it possible in `moment` JS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't want to format your date just yet or you'll just have a string representation, not a moment instance. Once you've taken care of that it's as simple as using `diff`:

```
 const dateStart = moment(1517812701107);
 const dateEnd = moment(1518331101107);
 const weeksBetween = dateEnd.diff(dateStart, 'weeks');
```

As for turning that into a progression array, you could simply loop through the result:

```
 const result = []
 for (let i = 1; i <= weeksBetween; i++) {
   result.push(i)
 }
```

The timestamps you provided are less than a week apart and will result in `0`. If you are aiming to find the exact ratio, add a floating point flag for the third variable:

```
 dateEnd.diff(dateStart, 'weeks', true); // 0.8571428571428571
```

Source:
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: thank you for the reply. i tried with this above code but not working for me

Comment: my week start from Monday and ends on Sunday, so right now I having week count is 1 right, I am getting empty array `result = []`

Comment: It's due to the difference returning 0 for results less than a week. You could update the for loop to use weeksBetween + 1. That would mean that 8 days would be counted as 2 weeks and 6 days or less would count as 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

You can try diff function, Try the following code. Hope this helps.

```
const dateStart = moment(1507812701107);
const dateEnd = moment(1518331101107);
const result = Array(dateEnd.diff(dateStart, 'week')).fill().map((e,i)=>i+1)
```

Comment: thanks you for the reply. for throwing an error for me `dateEnd.diff is not a function`

Comment: What is your weekEnd? Make sure it is a moment object. remove .format('DD-MM-YYYY')

Comment: i am getting the `result = []` empty

Comment: That is because your timestamps are not a week apart. You have to have timestamps that are weeks apart. try my example

Comment: my week start from Monday and ends on Sunday that means my result will be one right?

Comment: Might not be. The exact time matters, you need to take time difference so it includes a week. If not you need to like round times and do this. Or you can use the approach at the other answers bottom, that gives you a fractional number.